# Using CapsLocks as backspace

Tags: 18.04, xmodmap, keys

I want to use <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> as <kbd>Backspace</kbd>.
I tried commands below and it works.

```
setxkbmap -option caps:backspace
xmodmap -e "clear Lock"
```

But after restarting the computer, I need to type that commands again,how can I make it permanent?

version 18.04

Comment: Please edit your question indicating which version of Ubuntu you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to come up with a solution for Ubuntu 18.04 based on the first reply to [Remapping Keys : Ubuntu - Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/8lnr8q/remapping_keys/).

Open `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc` file in your favorite editor using:

```
sudoedit /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc
```

And comment out this line:

```
// key <CAPS> { [ Caps_Lock     ]   };
```

The difference is just what to put in the new line, which should be:

```
key <CAPS> {  [ BackSpace, BackSpace  ] };
```

Afterward, to activate the changes, hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, enter `r` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to restart `gnome-shell`.